# How the redirect URL Should be configured for shopify?

Tags: angularjs, node.js, shopify

I'm trying to develop an app in Shopify platform, in which I'm having hard time to bring my app as embedded inside Shopify. when ever i try to install after confirm installation it always redirected to the URL which I specified in redirect URL column of app settings.

Guide me how can i load my app inside Shopify web page itself.

**Note**

My app settings as follow:

**App URL (required) of my app is :** https://ngrok.io/sp-testapp/#/page/sh-register?appname=shopify

**Redirection URL (required) of my app is :** https://ngrok.io/sp-testapp/#/page/sh-register?appname=shopify

I have tried with different redirection URL and app URL which also loads out side of Shopify web page

I am using `node.js` as my back end and `shopify-node-api` library as OAuth2 Module for Shopify API

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

**Redirect Url:**
After a merchant authorizes your app, they can be redirected back to any of these URLs (that your enter in "redirect url textbox" during setting app). You can specify the URL using the redirect_uri parameter during the authorization step.

Please refer below URL

https://help.shopify.com/api/tutorials/building-public-app#step-2-configuring-your-application